# What is required of a class to allow auto-keyword instantiation?

Tags: c++, c++11, auto

The C++11 provides the following syntax for variable instantiation/initialisation; i.e.

```
auto myClass = MyClass{};
```

However, what is required of a class, in terms of copy-ability, move-ability and assign-ability, for this syntax to be allowed?

Visual studio 2013 (update 2) allows this form of instantiation even if copy constructor, copy assignment operator, move constructor and move assignment operator have all been deleted, whereas GCC (4.7.2) allows this only if move constructor is defaulted or implemented, or the move constructor is not defined (i.e. not deleted) and the copy constructor is defaulted or implemented.

What is required according to the standard?

Comment: Copy- or Move-ctor are needed for the assignment to be legit, default ctor for the construction, dtor for allowing auto-storage-class objects, anonymous or not. Actually used are only default ctor and dtor, due to copy-ellision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't have anything to do with `auto`, the results would be the same if you'd used this instead

```
MyClass myClass = MyClass{};
```

This is copy initialization, and it requires an accessible copy/move constructor. If you implement / explicitly default the move constructor, a temporary `MyClass` object will be created and then moved. If you do not explicitly delete the move constructor, but explicitly default / implement the copy constructor, then the move constructor is implicitly deleted, and the temporary `MyClass` instance will be copied over.

If you explicitly delete the move constructor then the initialization will be ill-formed. Similarly, if you explicitly delete the copy constructor, and do not explicitly default / implement the move constructor, the initialization will be ill-formed.

Note that the copy/move will most likely be elided by the compiler, but they're still required for the initialization.

Comment: "Note that the copy/move will most likely be elided by the compiler, but they're still required for the initialization." except when the compiler is MSVC, which does not notice the absence of an accessible copy/move constructor when the copy/move is elided, causing us to have to answer this question every few weeks.